# Number of steps till n items are consumed by m consumers

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

My problem can be reduced to the following:

**Problem Statement:**

I have `n` items and `m` consumers. Each item has some size `s` (positive integer).

During a step each consumer can choose an item and decrease its size by `1`. Two consumers can't choose the same item, an item can be left unchosen (imagine a injective function from consumers to items).

**My question:**

What's the minimal number of steps neccessary to consume all items (size of all items is 0)?

Note: I'm not sure about the complexity of this problem, I'm fine if the solution isn't optimal, close to optimal is fine.

**Examples:**

```
// First example:
// number of items
n = 4;

// size of each item, itemSizes[i] represents the size of item i
int[] itemSizes = {1, 1, 2, 4};

// number of consumers
m = 3;

// the result should be 4
int result = computeMinimumNumberOfSteps(n, m, itemSizes);


// Second example:
// number of items
n = 4;

// size of each item, itemSizes[i] represents the size of item i
int[] itemSizes = {4, 9, 5, 5};

// number of consumers
m = 2;

// the result should be 13
int result = computeMinimumNumberOfSteps(n, m, itemSizes);
```

**My approach:**

I use a greedy approach. I used to repeat the following steps till all items are consumed:

1. pick the `m` largest items (sort and pick first `m` items whose `size != 0`)
2. decrease their sizes by 1 (consume)
3. update number of steps (steps++)

This seems to slow, now I do:

1. pick the `m` largest items (sort and pick first `m` items whose `size != 0`)
2. find the minimal value `min`out of those `m` items.
3. decrease their sizes by the minimum value `min` (several consume steps combined)
4. Update the number of steps (steps += min)

This still seems too slow. What do you think about my approach? Is there a way to speed this up further?

Also, the problem seems pretty general, do you know of any well known problem to which my problem is reducible?

Comment: Isn't it the sum of the sizes divided by m?

Comment: @MauricePerry No, because it's not possible to decrement an item by more than 1 during a step. So if there is only 1 item with size 5, the minimum number of steps in which it can be consumed by infinite consumers is 5.

Comment: @AnnaVopureta, Why is the result of 1st example is 8? Shouldn't it be 4? first consume [4,2,1] so the array will be [3,1,0,1], then consume [3,1,1] it will be [2,0,0,0], then another 2 steps to consume 2.

Comment: Just a note: Don't write examples, write tests. They look about the same, but they *assert* (not using the keyword `assert`, but something like `org.junit.assertEquals`) the result. This means, you run it and don't have to look at the results when the tests pass. You can automate it, so it gets done before every commit (or whatever unit of work is relevant to you).

Comment: @maaartinus the point of the examples above is to convey the essence of the problem, having unnecessary boilerplate code in there wouldn't help imo.

Comment: You'd actually *save* one line by writing `assertEquals(8, 
computeMinimumNumberOfSteps(n, m, itemSizes))` instead.

Comment: @IslamHassan you're right, my bad. Fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is equivalent to the scheduling problem P|pmtn|C<sub>max</sub>, i.e. you have a number of parallel machines P, your jobs can be preempted (pmtn) and you want to minimize the maximum makespan C<sub>max</sub>.

McNaughton's rule provides an optimal solution to this problem, you can find a reference to it in the paper [Scheduling Algorithms](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/abcc/ef7de5cbf66a54b5d7a4a785079f238c4255.pdf) by David Karger et al. (Chapter 2.3.1). Basically, you assign to a consumer arbitrary items until you reach **D**=max(sum(itemsizes)/m, max(itemSizes)), and then continue with the next consumer. Consequently, the runtime of this algorithm is **D**.

Comment: Thanks for the paper, It led me to the LPT algorithm which solves my problem. Implementation of the alg: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/25applications/LPT.java